# CodeIgniter controllers conflict with sub folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, conflict, subdirectory

I wrote a controller named Admin with method `index` and placed as `/application/controllers/admin.php` for URL `http://localhost/admin`.

Then I wrote another controller named Account inside `/application/controllers/admin/` folder, with a method `login` for URL `http://localhost/admin/account/login`.

But the problem is when I visit `/admin/account/login` I got a 404. I don't know why? Or how can I define this 2 path in my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same problem but for only solution was to either rename the subfolder name or rename the outside controller name.

Answer (score 0):

Try put admin/account/login  before admin, something like this:

```
 $route ['admin/account/login'] = 'admin/account/login';

 $route ['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

Comment: This may work, but too complex for more controllers under `admin/` subfolder.